# Shell Programming How to count how many times a word appears in a line?

Tags: shell, awk, count, line, cpu-word

How to count how many times a word appears in a line?
For example, I have the word "man" and the following lines:

```
a man walks here
nobody over here
from man to man
```

The result should be: on the first line, once, on the second line 0 times and on the last one twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk you can do this easily:

```
awk -F 'man' '{print (NF?NF-1:0)}' file

1
0
2
```

`-F 'man'` sets input field separator as `man` and `NF` prints # of fields for each row.

In case you want to count full words then use this `gnu-awk`:

```
awk -F '\\<man\\>' '{print (NF?NF-1:0)}' file
```

For non-gnu awk you can use this:

```
awk -F '(^|[^[:alnum:]])man([^[:alnum:]]|$)' '{print (NF?NF-1:0)}' file
```

Comment: I can't tell if this solution is janky or beautiful.

Comment: It's worth noting that this will count words *containing* man as well, throw a line with affirmance, manager, or other words like that and you'll count those too.  May not be a big deal as the asker does not specify if we want just the whole word man or occurence of that text, but this does the latter as it stands.

Just adding spaces to the delimiter arg will get you just the whole word, e.g. `awk -F ' man ' '{print NF-1}'`

Comment: Good point @zzevannn I've added an option to count complete words as well.

Comment: I see, but if the separator of the words is not space, how could this be done easily and nice? EDIT: nevermind, i got the answer from @anubhava, ty again!

Comment: @anubhava One more thing, if i want to use a variable instead of man, how should i do it beucae '\\<$var\\>' is not working properly.

Comment: @J.Newbie: You can use: **`s='man'; awk -F "\\\<$s\\\>" '{print NF-1}' file`**

Comment: Thank you, again, @anubhava but can you explain why 3 backslashes are required?

Comment: I did a quick google and it looks like on BSD awk the problem appears when the condition is a test such as `awk 'BEGIN{print 1==1?1:0}' file` instead of `awk 'BEGIN{print (1==1?1:0)}' file`. idk about other awks or other situations.

Comment: I would not question @EdMorton's awk knowledge - if he says that's a syntax error in some `awk`s, it is.  :) But I have confirmed that it works fine without parentheses in BSD awk (20070501 and 20110810), gawk (4.1.3), mawk (1.3.4 20141027), and nawk (20121220).

Comment: @MarkReed thanks for the vote of confidence but this falls into the "stuff Ed doesn't actually care about" category so it's entirely possible that the posted ternary expression is one you can get away with leaving unparenthesized (like you can get away with leaving some shell variables unquoted) - I've just always parenthesized them as they're hard to read otherwise and as a nice side-effect I never have to think about which flavors of ternary expression in which statements produce syntax errors in which awks.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to count `mankind` or other string containing `man`, you can break on whitespace and loop over each field:

```
$ awk '{c=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^man$/) c++; print c}' file
```

If you want to use a variable:

```
$ awk -v m=man '{c=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i==m) c++; print c FS m}' file
```

If you have `gawk` vs POSIX awk, you can do:

```
$ awk '{n=gsub(/\<man\>/, ""); print n}' file
```

Comment: appreciate the simplicity of this approach

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
a man walks here
nobody over here

from man to man

$ awk -v tgt="man" '{print gsub("(^|[[:space:]])"tgt"([[:space:]]|$)","&")}' file
1
0
0
2
```

The above will work in any awk, it just relies on the words being space-separated.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to see a linenumber, and skip lines without occurances, you can try something like

```
grep -no man file | uniq -c | cut -d":" -f1 | xargs printf "%d occurances in line %s\n"
```

Comment: OS X utilities insert a CR in lines where there is more than 1 match like `from man to man` so renders this inop on OS X

Comment: @dawg I thought I fixed that with the the `uniq -c`

Answer (score 0):

Give this version a try: it enables multi-files search and the generated output looks like **grep -nH**:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  word=ARGV[1];
  ARGV[1]="";
  print "Filename:Line #:" word " #:source line";
}
{
  count=0;
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    if ($i == word) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  print FILENAME ":" FNR ":" count ":" $0;
}
```

The test:

```
$ ls
file  speach.txt  wordgrep.awk

$ cat file
a man walks here
nobody over here
from man to man

$ cat speach.txt
An old man is equal to any other man
Petrol is not good for life

$ ./wordgrep.awk man file speach.txt
Filename:Line #:man #:source line
file:1:1:a man walks here
file:2:0:nobody over here
file:3:2:from man to man
speach.txt:1:2:An old man is equal to any other man
speach.txt:2:0:Petrol is not good for life
```